# Is flag usage different on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I do a lot of flagging on Stack Overflow to clean the site. When you review "first answers" or "late answers" you often fall on answer that are not answer and that post some code and finish by a question about their code. Even though the problem is often related to the OP, if it's not an answer, then the post is removed or edited to clean what isn't an answer.

I was doing some reviewing here and felt on a post where one of the answer ended actually in a question, so I flagged it. Basically, the guy post his own code of something that was doing the same thing as OP and then asked others what did they think about HIS version. Well, even though the code is related, it's not a real answer as the guy is asking for review on his code. Yes it's the same "algorithm" but still, the way he asked for review was making his post a question post not an answer post.

My flagged got declined for  "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". Which I don`t really understand, because to me that does not fit in the context. I flagged to tell that the "answer" was a question with the "not an answer" flag.

I have read the Code Review ["How To Answer"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) section but didn't see any major difference with the SO one.

I can provide the post link if needed but didn't want to post it at first as the exact post is not, to me as important as the situation.

**ttl;dr:**

I was wondering if this is something specific to code review to kind of have answers with a variant of the OP also "asking for review", in order to group variants of algorithms altogether. Or should I continue flagging the same way I do on Stack Overflow, and that only a weird declined flag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I consider this to be an edge case — [the disputed answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23303/9390) is a bit ambiguous. The question at the end could be interpreted as a review request (which would make it *not an answer*) or a simple request for feedback on the answer (which would make it a *valid answer*).

I consider it to be an acceptable answer because it does contain criticism of the code and suggest an alternative approach. I agree that the answer could use some clarification and editing.

If you believe that an important point has been neglected in this dicussion, feel free to bring it up.
Or better yet, edit the disputed answer to make it more useful and clear.

> ## The bottom line
>
> **Abusing answers to ask a new or similar question is not allowed.** Such "answers" will be deleted, as they always have been on all Stack Exchange sites.
>
> The disputed answer, however, does seem to have the characteristics required for it to count as an answer.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer! As I'm newly trying to get active on CR I need to learn about potential differences with SO!